# How to change AppleScript path to a Terminal-style path?

Tags: applescript

I have a custom Service that I've created in Automater (I'm on OS X 10.6.5). The Service executes an AppleScript which in turn executes a shell script. Here is the AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & input & " -type f -name .DS_Store -delete -print"
    display alert "Path: " & input
end run
```

The problem is, the path passed by the Service (in the variable `input`) looks like:

```
Macintosh HD:Users:Matthew:Documents:Programming:Apple Scripts:
```

And for the command to execute properly, the path needs to look like:

```
Macintosh\ HD/Users/Matthew/Documents/Programming/Apple\ Scripts/
```

So, is there a way to translate the first path to the second path? I was hoping for a core function which handles this. But I suppose some kind of regex/find/replace/etc would work? I'm familiar with HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP, not with Cocoa/AppleScript/C. Any direction or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok...this was easier than I had realized. After some Googling, it looks like what I need here is the `POSIX path of` command. This converts a given path to a Unix style path, which is the type of path you would see/use in Terminal. So:

```
POSIX path of input
```

Gives me a path like:

```
/Users/Matthew/Documents/Programming/Apple Scripts/
```

It seems to take into account that you just need a `/` at the beginning of the path, rather than the hard drive name. It does not, however, escape `\` spaces (or handle special characters) in the path. So, as the other answer here mentions, you need to place the path in quotes ( `"` or `'` ) in order for those spaces (or special characters) to be interpreted literally. You accomplish this by using `quoted form of`. Here it is:

```
quoted form of the POSIX path of the input
-- gives a path like: '/Users/Matthew/Documents/Programming/Apple Scripts/'
```

Comment: The `/` at the beginning of the path is the boot volume. Other hard drives are under `/Volumes/`

Answer (score 9):

Use `quoted form of the POSIX path of input`.  Without the `quoted form of` part, it won't handle funny characters (like spaces) in filenames correctly.  See [this Apple technote](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html%23TNTAG4).